# Deep Trouble with values not inserting to sqlite database -iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

i have multiple view controllers, registrationviewcontroller , contactsviewcontroller , addnewcontactsviewcontroller, etc.

i have the below code in registrationviewcontroller

```
 DatabaseCRUD *database = [[DatabaseCRUD alloc] init];
       NSMutableString *registrationquery=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"insert into BARvalues values ('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')",[name text],[emailAddress text],[mobileNumber text],[password text],[country text],@"0"];
        NSLog(@"registrationquery is %@",registrationquery);
            [database updatenewregistration:registrationquery];
            [database release];

            DatabaseCRUD *database1 = [[DatabaseCRUD alloc] init];
            NSMutableString *registrationquery1=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"insert into contacts values ('1234','1234')"];
            NSLog(@"registrationquery is %@",registrationquery1);
            [database1 updatenewregistration:registrationquery1];
            [database1 release];

            DatabaseCRUD *database2 = [[DatabaseCRUD alloc] init];
            NSMutableString *registrationquery2=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"insert into contacts values ('abcd','abcd')"];
            NSLog(@"registrationquery is %@",registrationquery2);
            [database2 addcontacts:registrationquery2];
            [database2 release];
```

the above code works fine . it inserts the values into the sqlite database. Here is the problem , i have the almost same code in a different viewcontroller(contacts, addcontacts) and the values dont get inserted into the sqlite database.Here is the code.

```
DatabaseCRUD *database = [[DatabaseCRUD alloc] init];
NSMutableString *registrationquery=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"insert into contacts values ('raja','shekar')"];
NSLog(@"registrationquery is %@",registrationquery);
[database updatenewregistration:registrationquery];
[database release];

DatabaseCRUD *database1 = [[DatabaseCRUD alloc] init];
NSMutableString *registrationquery1=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"insert into contacts values ('rajesh','neelam')"];
NSLog(@"registrationquery is %@",registrationquery1);
[database1 addcontacts:registrationquery1];
[database1 release];
```

i dont see any reason why the database object would insertin in one viewcontroller and doesnt in the other viewcontroller. Any help will be greatly appreciated. i have tried to figure where the error is all day long and i dont want to waste anymore time. any help please????

I put breakpoints at every method of database object to see if its inserting, there is no error at all . it seems to be passing through the sqlstatment, but no insertion happens. Here is the code of saving the values in databaseHere is the code for database insertion.

```
-(void) addcontacts :(NSString *)query
{

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"query is %@",query);
        sqlStatement=[query cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSLog(@"new contact updated");
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);  
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is compiledStatement defined?  (s/b sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement = nil;)  And, it would be best if this was defined in your addcontacts method.

Comment: One more thing, sqlite3_step on an insert returns SQLITE_DONE, not SQLITE_ROW

Comment: @kevinDTimm I don't have SQLITE_DONE in my updatenewregistration method,but it still inserts. LIke I said both methods work fine from registrstionviewcontroller, and they don't work from other view controllers

Comment: Which means that you have no idea why it works - make the correct tests and print out the errors that you receive.  That's all you'll need to do to ascertain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Post the correct code (as you mentioned below, this isn't what is actually in place)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhere between an answer and a comment - interpret as necessary.

I assume that the insert statements return some error code, correct?  What are their values?  This will send you a long ways towards your solution.

Comment: in put breakpoints at every method of database object to see if its inserting, there is no error at all . it seems to be passing through the sqlstatment, but no insertion happens. Here is the code of saving the values in database.

Comment: Here is the code that does the insertion into the database          -(void) addcontacts :(NSString *)query
{
 
 if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
 {
  NSLog(@"query is %@",query);
  sqlStatement=[query cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
  
  if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
  {
   while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
   {
    NSLog(@"new contact updated");
   }
   sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);  
  }
  sqlite3_close(database);
 }
}

Comment: @Rajashekar - add this code to your post, it's not legible as a comment

Comment: So, you get 'new contact updated' in the log after each update?

Comment: @KEvinDTimm No , I don't get that log, successful insertions don't go into the while loop, I forgot to remove those statements.

Comment: And so, that means that you don't know if (or why) something works.  Change to SQLITE_DONE and print the error when it fails (which it certainly does).

Comment: @KevinDTimm , tried with SQLITE_DONE and it did not work , but surely it gave me thought to user other options like SQLITE_MISUSE ,SQLITE_BUSY. when i used SQLITE_BUSY it went into the while loop which gave me a clear indication that some other object was trying to access the same database at the same time. did some trial and error with commenting out database objects and found the culprit. it was the viewwillappear method of the parentviewcontroller. apparently i was using 2 database objects one in my dismissviewcontroller method and other in viewwillapear method.that was causing the problem.

Comment: Excellent - as I expected, once you utilized the return values, you fixed the problem.

Comment: @KevinDTimm thanks a tonn and without your help i would have been wasting more time. i really appreciate your efforts. by the way i would like to know one more thing. how would you NSLOG the sqlite errors , just in case i have any in the future. ONCE AGAIN THOUSAND *'S FOR YOU.

Comment: const char *sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3*);
 (http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) will return a an english text string of the error message